# Is it possible to read data from an excel file without uploading it to the server in VB.Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

I need to be able to read the data from an excel file and upload the data to a database after validating it.

However, the server I'm working with does not allow write privileges for the web applications, so I need to know if it is possible to read from an excel file without writing it to the server through upload?

So far I haven't been able to find a clear answer.

Thanks!

Comment: You did not tell how you are reading the excel file. If you are using OleDb, you have a problem because the connection string requires a file. Well, as far as I know.

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your upload control is called `fileUpload`.

You don't need to do a `fileUpload.SaveAs("path")`. You can read the stream with `fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream`. I used this for a zip file with excel sheets in it (the library is Ionic by the way):

```
using (var file = ZipFile.Read(fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream))
{
    foreach (var zipEntry in file.Where(ze => ze.FileName.EndsWith(".xls")
                                           || ze.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx")))
    {
        // process the Excel files here.
    }
}
```

Sorry, I'm not very familiar with VB.net, so the following might be wrong. But because you asked for a VB.net version:

```
Using file As var = ZipFile.Read(fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream)
    For Each zipEntry As var In file.Where(ze => ze.FileName.EndsWith(".xls") or ze.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
        ' process the Excel files here.
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: What about just a single file? Is there a standard way of accessing the data inside? Looping through and storing the data?

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to your question: As far as I know, there are 2 ways reading excel files. One is using the excel library, which is very slow and buggy, and I don't know if it can read excel files from stream. Or you use the OleDb provider, which needs a file as the source. If there is another option, I'm not aware of it. My example just should show you how you could use a stream.